# What does "class" mean in this quotation?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I've learned one very interesting thing about money...it doesn't buy
>   class.

I have no idea what the word "class" means in this quotation.

Comment: "Admirable behavior; elegance" ([Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/class#Noun)), "a quality that makes something or someone seem special and attractive; a quality that makes someone seem very good, kind, etc." ([Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/class)). Cf. also: [*classy*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/classy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Class**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/class?show=0&t=1340461450), here, refers to *admirable quality; elegance*.

- Apologizing for losing your temper, even though you were badly provoked, showed real **class**.
- She showed a lot of **class** by donating her prize money to charity.

Answer (score 1):

"Class" here means [elegance of style and manner](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/class)